# homeomorphism betwwen $\mathbb{R} \times {0}$ and $(0,1)\times {0} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $$A=\left\lbrace \left( x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0, 0<x<1  \right\rbrace $$
$$B=\left\lbrace \left( x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=0 \right\rbrace $$
then:
1.$A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.
2. There is not a homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $h(A)=B$

For part 1. $f:A \longrightarrow B$ and $g:B \longrightarrow A$ defined by $f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},y \right) $ and $g(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}},y \right) $ are continuous and $(f\circ g) \left(x,y \right)=\left(x,y\right)   $ and $(g\circ f ) \left(x,y \right)=\left(x,y\right)  $ then $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

I dont know how to solve part 2, I dont have theory about open set and closed set, only the definition of continuity with $\epsilon, \delta$.

Comment: But Part 1 refutes Part 2

Comment: No, Part 2 says that a homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ doesnt can be extended to a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $h$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R^{2}$ then the function $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^{2}$ defined by $g(t)=h(t,0)$ is continuous. But any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is bounded. This implies that any homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^{2}$ has to be bounded on $A$. But $h(A)=B$ is not bounded. Hence such a homeomorphism cannot exist.

Comment: But you need to talk about (0,1)

Comment: If a function is bounded on $[0,1]$ is is also bounded on $(0,1)$. Note that $h$ is defined on the whole of $\mathbb  R^{2}$ so $h(t,0)$ is defined for $t=0$ and $t=1$ also. @OrShahar

Comment: Ok, I got it. Nice.